# R : How to create multilinestring sf from a tibble of coordinates

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf, multilinestring

Consider the following tibble :

```
my_tible <- tibble("ID" = c("A","A","A","B","B", "C","C") , X=  c(647851,647875,647875,647766,647766,647826,647822) , 
               Y=c(6859335,6859318,6859319,6859028,6859030,6859314,6859316) )
```

I would like to create a sf multilinestring object based on that tibble :

```
my_tible %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise("geometry" = c(X,Y) %>% 
          as.numeric() %>% 
          matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = F) %>% 
          list() %>% 
          st_multilinestring()) %>% 
   st_sf() %>% 
   st_set_crs("+init=epsg:2154") %>% 
   st_transform(crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

I got the following message after st_sf() :
"Error in st_sf(.) : no simple features geometry column present."

I would like to understand what I am doing wrong.

Solution :

```
my_tible %>% 
  st_as_sf( coords = c("X", "Y")) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize() %>%
  st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>% 
  st_set_crs("+init=epsg:2154") %>% 
  st_transform(crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

Comment: Hi Felipe, If you found a solution, I think it would  be better if you post it as an answer and accept it (even if it is your own answer), instead than adding it within the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution :

```
my_tible %>% 
  st_as_sf( coords = c("X", "Y")) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize() %>%
  st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>% 
  st_set_crs("+init=epsg:2154") %>% 
  st_transform(crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```